# Contour Plotting on Objective-C

Tags: python, ios, objective-c, matplotlib, contourf

The Problem:

I am trying to create an iphone app in Xcode that takes data (some matrix) and creates a contour plot in uiimageview. So far, I have not found a way to directly make contour plots using objective-c, so i started trying to embed python into objective c, create the contour plot and save it as a png and then access it through uiimageview. However, matplotlib does not exist in any python framework that i have tried to embed into objective-c and xcode. I don't necessarily need to use python, but I thought it would be a fairly simple way of accessing matplotlib.

The question:

Is there a way to embed matplotlib into objective-c? Or is there a better way to create a contour plot in objective-c?

Comment: Maybe going through C/C++ : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509156/anyone-knows-a-matplotlib-equivalent-in-c-or-c ?